# Compare columns in two files in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two files with space delimited columns. I wish to compare them in the following way.

File1.txt:

```
prduct-name sub-prod price
==========================
xxxxx       a1         12
xxxxx       a2         12
yyyyy       b1         13
```

File2.txt:

```
prduct-name sub-prod price
==========================
xxxxx       a1         12
xxxxx       x2         12
yyyyy       b1         13
```

I wish to compare and report which prduct-name & its sub-prod & price is not matching with each other files:

I am very new to Perl. Please help me out.

Comment: Being new to Perl does not automatically mean that people will do your assignments for you. Please take a [tour] of [so] and learn [ask] good questions.

Comment: Take a look at http://learn.perl.org/

Answer (score 4):

Ok, where exactly are you having trouble?

1. Open one of the files
2. Skip past the header rows
3. For each line in the file
4. Split the line into three fields
5. Store the data in a hash (keyed on the product name)
6. If there are more lines, goto 3.
7. Open the other file
8. Skip past the header rows
9. For each line in the file
10. Split the line into three fields
11. Look for the product name in your hash
12. If it is missing, display a warning
13. If it is there, check the other two values
14. If they are different, display a warning
15. If there are more lines in the file, goto 9

Translate that to Perl and you're done :-)

Answer (score 0):

grep -vf <(perl -ne 'if (($seen{$*} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/) { print $* }'  file1.txt   file2.txt ) file2.txt

(this command will output all entries of file2.txt which doesn't have an exact match in file1.txt)

for finding entries from file1.txt reverse the file names in above command i.e.
grep -vf <(perl -ne 'if (($seen{$*} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/) { print $* }'  file1.txt   file2.txt ) file1.txt